# Vuejs dynamic async component not loading

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have the following App component:

HTML:

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-content>
          <template v-if="!authenticated">
            <login @loginSuccess="authenticated = true"></login>
          </template>
          <template v-if="authenticated">
            <mainframe @logout="authenticated = false"></mainframe>
          </template>
       </v-content>
     </v-app>
   </div>
</template
```

Script:

```
import Login from './components/Login'
import Mainframe from './components/Mainframe'
export default{
    name: 'app',
    components: {
        Publiccontainer,
        Login,
        Mainframe,
    },
    data () {
        return {
            authenticated: false
        }
    }
}
```

And I have my mainframe component:

HTML:

```
<template>
   <v-container>
     <component :is="component"></component>
   </v-container>
</template>
```

Script:

```
export default{
    data: () => ({
        selected: `<h1>Hello</h1>`,
    }),
    computed: {
        component() {
            return {
                template: this.selected
            };
        }
    }
}
```

As simple as it is it doesn't work. The mainframe component is rendered but the dynamic async component binding is not working. The "Hello" is not displayed. If I try to reproduce it in a code pen it works fine. I have really no clue what I do wrong. I am thankful for any suggestion. My console shows no errors and the component is registered correctly.

Comment: Check your Capitalization. When you declare the names in the JS, they are capitalized (Mainframe, Login) while in your HTML they are lowercase (mainframe, login). See if changing that will help.

Comment: Can you post the Codepen where you had it working correctly?